# window.open("chrome://history/")

Tags: javascript

`window.open("ссылка")` - откроется новое окно (вкладка) и в нём отобразится "ссылка". Как сделать так, чтобы в этом окне отобразилась не "ссылка", а история посещений браузера Хром (`chrome://history/`)?
Спасибо.

Comment: Программно никак.

Comment: Вы расширение для браузера или веб-сайт разрабатываете? Если второе, то никак. Если первое, то вам нужен метод [`chrome.tabs.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create).

Answer (score 0):

Поведение Chrome для window.open зависит от того, откуда она вызывается.

Когда window.open вызывается из скрипта,  например, OnClick событие, Chrome будет вести себя подобно тому, как будто вы нажали на ,  откроется новая пустая вкладка. Но если ввести через адресную строку, Chrome  откроет вкладку со служебной информацией.

По мнению разработчиков это сделано в целях безопасности.